# Excel VBA 1004 error on variable assignment

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a script/macro to compare values between an existing spreadsheet and an import spreadsheet. I am trying to identify any changes. As part of this I am searching for the name and id of each item on the proof sheet on the old sheet. When I try to assign the name and id to a variable on a loop, I get a 1004 error

I've tried changing the way I reference the cell, and the order in which I reference them, but that doesn't seem to matter, the same line keeps causing an error

The line throwing the error is the id assignment.

```
            Dim name As String
            Dim id As String


            name = Sheets(proofsheet).Range(destItemColumn & m).Text
            id = Sheets(proofsheet).Range(destIdColumn & m).Text
```

The bulk of the operation is done here:

```
proofLRow = Sheets(proofsheet).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For m = 2 To proofLRow
        If Not (InStr(Sheets(proofsheet).Range(destIdColumn1 & m), "TBD") = 0) Then
            Dim name As String
            Dim id As String


            name = Sheets(proofsheet).Range(destItemColumn & m).Text
            id = Sheets(proofsheet).Range(destIdColumn & m).Text

            Dim idFound, nameFound As Boolean
            idFound = False
            nameFound = False
            For k = 2 To prevDataLRow
                searchId = Sheets(sheet).Range(sourceIdColumn & k)
                searchName = Sheets(sheet).Range(sourceItemColumn & k)
                If (searchId = id) Then
                    idFound = True
                End If
                If (searchName = name) Then
                    nameFound = True
                End If
                If (nameFound Or idFound) Then
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next

            If idFound Then
                Sheets(proofsheet).Range(destFlagColumn & m).Value = ""
            ElseIf nameFound Then
                Sheets(proofsheet).Range(destFlagColumn & m).Value = "Replace"
            Else
                Sheets(proofsheet).Range(destFlagColumn & m).Value = "Retired"
            End If

        End If

    Next
```

I should be at least be able to write the scanned data to a message box for comparison, but I keep getting either this 1004 error, or when I tried to put the search in a function, I would get a compile error about a type mismatch.

Comment: `id = Sheets(proofsheet).Range(destIdColumn & m).Text` If this is the line which fails please use the debugger to find out the contents of the variables and  post them.

Comment: There are 9 instances of `Sheets(proofsheet)` in that snippet alone. Consider pulling the result of that member call into a local variable - `Set proofSheet = Worksheets(proofsheetName)` (notice the variable name change), and then working off `proofsheet` (the new `Worksheet` object variable) instead of dereferencing the same object over and over every time it's needed.

Comment: If the `name` assignment works, there's no reason for the `id` assignment to blow up. Place a breakpoint (F9) on the instruction and validate that the parameters are correct and every value is as expected. Keep in mind that an unqualified `Sheets` call goes against whatever the `ActiveWorkbook` is - consider qualifying it with an explicit `Workbook` object.

Comment: There was a section of code I didn't include where I instantiated the variable with the wrong name. I'm having an issue where I can't see the debugger on mouse-over or any of the menu drop downs anymore, so I missed that the values were blank. I got the code working now, though I have to use immediate to do all my debugging now. Thank you!